# GCP c# 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' when adding object to NetworkInterfaces List<NetworkInterface>

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm getting the classic

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

error when adding an Google.Apis.Compute.v1 NetworkInterface object to a list of NetworkInterface's.

```
Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.Instance requestBody = new Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.Instance();
requestBody.MachineType = "zones/us-east1-b/machineTypes/n1-standard-1";
requestBody.Name = "lolzorpbn";
requestBody.Scheduling = new Scheduling() { Preemptible = true };
NetworkInterface FailingNetworkObject = new NetworkInterface() { Name = "eth0",  Network = "global/networks/default", AccessConfigs =  new List<AccessConfig>() { new AccessConfig() {  Type = "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT" , Name = "External NAT" } } };
requestBody.NetworkInterfaces.Add(FailingNetworkObject);
```

The object is instantiated and when inspecting the error it gives no further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate your own `IList<NetworkInterface>`, and assign it to the property:

```
Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.Instance requestBody = new Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data.Instance();
requestBody.NetworkInterfaces = new List<NetworkInterface>
{
    new NetworkInterface { ... }
};
```